# wordpress "REST API" wpbackery page builder and Ionic

Tags: angular, angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework

I'm requesting Content from WordPress website built with wpbackery page builder by REST API in ionic app but i have a problem :
the Contents created by "VisualComposer" looks like this :

[image]

how can i extract the content to get the text and images only , is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code on the WordPress side, `function.php`.

For example, you can add another key to the response that returns from the call to the API by adding the following code to function.php (adding another key to the response called `htmlcontent`):

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
   register_rest_field('page', 'htmlcontent', array(
      'get_callback'    => 'page_do_shortcodes',
      'update_callback' => null,
      'schema'          => null,
   ));
});

function page_do_shortcodes( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
   WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();
   global $post;
   $post = get_post ($object['id']);
   $output['rendered'] = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
   return $output;
}
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite the original key that comes back from api, the `content` key :

(*Note: The only change from the code shown above is the second parameter passed to the `register_rest_field` function*)

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
   register_rest_field('page', 'content', array(
      'get_callback'    => 'page_do_shortcodes',
      'update_callback' => null,
      'schema'          => null,
   ));
});

function page_do_shortcodes( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
   WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();
   global $post;
   $post = get_post ($object['id']);
   $output['rendered'] = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
   return $output;
}
```